# Rails 4 routing with optional params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I set an optional param in my signup route:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/signin', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/signup(/:sign_up_key)', to: 'users/registrations#new'
end
```

Before the optional param was there I could do:

```
signup_path
```

Rack routes shows:

```
signin GET    /signin(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
       GET    /signup(/:sign_up_key)(.:format)    users/registrations#new
```

Now `signup_path` is no longer available? How do I get it back with the optional param there?

By the way I am routing like this:

```
<%= link_to '/signup' ... %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%= link_to signup_path ... %>
```

Would like to get access to the prefix back? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `as: :singup`:

```
get '/signup(/:sign_up_key)', to: 'users/registrations#new', as: :signup
```